# addClass after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

Easy stuff, 
In the following script, I'm adding the class "mobile" to the  element.

Target of the script is that of providing responsiveness feature to my theme through require.js based on screen resolution.

It should be almost self-explanatory, but *I don't understand why it just gets inserted on the homepage*: if I open whatever other page the mobile class isn't there.

```
(function($) {
var htmlCache = { desktop: null, mobile: null };

var reload_page = function(mobile) {
  var bodyHtml = '';

  if(mobile && htmlCache.mobile)
    bodyHtml = htmlCache.mobile;
  else if(!mobile && htmlCache.desktop)
    bodyHtml = htmlCache.desktop;
  else
    $.ajax(location.href, {
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      data: {
        ajax: 1,
        force_mobile: mobile ? 1 : null
      },
      success: function(data)
        {
          if(mobile) {
            htmlCache.mobile = data;
          }
          else
            htmlCache.desktop = data;
          bodyHtml = data;
        },
      dataType: 'html'
    });

  $('body').html(bodyHtml);
};

$(function() {
  // Be responsive only on desktop
  if($('body').hasClass('mobile')) {
    return;
  } else {
    htmlCache.desktop = $('body').html();

    enquire.register('screen and (max-width:1080px)', {
      match: function() {
        reload_page(true);
        $('body').addClass('mobile');
        $('<link />', {
          rel: 'stylesheet',
          id: 'mobile-css',
          href: 'http://dev.andreapuiatti.com/dev0/wp-content/themes/spk/mobile.css?ver=3.6',
          media: 'all'
        }).appendTo('head');
      },
    });

    enquire.register('screen and (min-width:1081px)', {
      match: function() {
        reload_page(false);
        $('body').removeClass('mobile');
        $('#mobile-css').remove();
      },
    });
  }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you provide a smaller subset that reproduce your problem ?

Comment: @blue112: Thank you! this is the theme: http://goo.gl/a4H1Yy As you can see if you activate whatever mobile user agent, the first page gets loaded with the class "mobile" in the <body> element, but from there if you click whatever other link, it disappears and the mobile theme shows up not styled